# Good/functional but can do better

Tags: aphorism-requests

I'm looking for an aphorism communicating the thought that "this works, but we can do better". Some high-falutin language like Shakespeare or Blake would be ideal.

Comment: "If it ain't broke, go fix it anyway."

Comment: Who's the "we" in "we can do better"? The same people who made the good-enough thing, or someone else (a competitor)? We need some more guidance on the sort of phrase you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally people would just say either of

- Not bad.
- Acceptable.
- Impressive.
- Nice.
- OK.
- Great.

However, let me recompose some of Yogi Berra's:

- Love is the most important thing, but your project/application is pretty good too.
- Little league projects are great, because it keeps engineers/programmers like you off the main concourse.
- You don't have to swing hard to hit a home run. Your application could just make it, with the right timing.

a'la Edgar Allen Poe:

- Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary. Nice app BTW.
- Words have no power to impress the mind without the exquisite horror of their reality after deployment.
- Science has not yet taught us if mediocrity is or is not the normality of intelligence.
- I have great faith in tools like these. My lack of confidence in them, I call it.
- After all most apps, my friend, are simply evolved out of fraud, fear, greed, imagination, and creativity.

a'la Hemmingway:

- Never mistake an acceptance as excellence.
- You do not have to like it just because it works.
- Happiness in intelligent people are the rarest thing I know. You seem pretty happy with your app.
- No app named horrid, has ever won the Nobel peace prize. We'll deploy it but expect lots of rotten eggs thrown at it.

Generic religious:

- The world was created in six days, so was your app. It's good enough.
- From the abundance of your heart, your app manifests.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite Shakespearean, but you could say

> Although the `<product>` is good as it is, there is still room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If "T'ain't broke don't fix it" be not your cry, go with the best, give it (us?) a try.

Comment: did you create this or is it a quote from someone?

Comment: I've never seen or heard it before so I suppose you could say that I created it. I flatter myself here, I know, but feel free to use it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

"To [paraphrase Mark Twain](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/4957-the-difference-between-the-right-word-and-the-almost-right), it's just a lightning bug and not lightning."

Answer (score 0):

Don't rest until you do your best.

Good enough isn't.